# combined three dataframes columns into single dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In pyspark, I have created three dataframes: B1, P1, C1.

```
    Dataframe: B1 has five columns (B_Num, B_Tin, B_Light, B_Dark, and 
    B_White)
    Dataframe: P1 has three columns(P_Prov, P_Tip, and P_Bye)
    Datafram: C1 has three columns(C_Cust, C_Addr1, and C_Addr2)
```

I tried doing union the three dataframes. It's working fine.I don't want 
    to do.

```
    B1 = B1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    P1 = P1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    C1 = C1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

    combined = B1.join(P1, "id", "outer").join(C1, "id", "outer").drop("id")
    display(combined)
```

Below is the output of the combined:

```
    B_Num, B_Tin, B_Light, B_Dark, B_White, P_Prov, P_Tip, P_Bye, C_Cust, 
    C_Addr1, and C_Addr2
```

I except the ouput like this:

```
B_Num,P_Prov,B_Tin,C_Addr2,B_Light,P_Tip,C_Cust,B_Dark,B_White,P_Bye,C_Addr1
```

Comment: Is your problem only the ordering of the columns ? Otherwise try giving a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes I want to have my columns in this order.
B_Num,P_Prov,B_Tin,C_Addr2,B_Light,P_Tip,C_Cust,B_Dark,B_White,P_Bye,C_Addr1

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is only the ordering of the columns (as mentioned in your comment), you can select them in the right order :

```
B1 = B1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
P1 = P1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
C1 = C1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

combined = B1.join(P1, "id", "outer").join(C1, "id", "outer").drop("id")

good_ordering = combined.select("B_Num", "P_Prov", "B_Tin", "C_Addr2", "B_Light", "P_Tip", "C_Cust", "B_Dark", "B_White", "P_Bye", "C_Addr1")
display(good_ordering)
>>> B_Num,P_Prov,B_Tin,C_Addr2,B_Light,P_Tip,C_Cust,B_Dark,B_White,P_Bye,C_Addr1
```